# Get caller method's name javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, call, classname

I'm developing a logger module in node.js, and I need to know the name of the method that is calling one of my logging functions, so the logging function can print where does the log come from.

For example, if the method **methodOne** from the class **classOne** wants to create a log, it will call one of the logging functions from my module **Logger**. This function will receive a message and print an output with the name of the method that wants to generate the log and the name of the class where it belongs. Since methods in javascript are anonymous functions, I can't get that name.

Do you guys know any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [console.trace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Stack_traces) or use `var stack = new Error().stack;`